# Working with ux-datagrid, angularJS and nested interations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datagrid

I got it working excellent with one template but ran into an issue trying to replace my inner ng-repeat with another template. Kind of like grouped data or more like nested data.

so let me simplify my html here:

```
  <div data-ng-controller="index.dataGridController" data-ux-datagrid="index.items" class="listA datagrid" data-addons="whichTemplate"  grouped="'focus'">
      <script type="template/html" data-template-name="default" data-template-item="item">
        <div>
            <h3>{{ item.obj.name }}</h3>
             <!--- instead of 
             <ul>
                 <li ng-repeat="listItem in item.focus>{{listitem}}</li>
              </uL
              -->
        </div>
      </script>
      <script type="template/html" data-template-name="innerFocus" data-template-item="item">
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>{{item.focus.id}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </script>
  </div>
```

and the index.items look like this:

```
[{
    "obj": {
    "name": "someName" 
    }
    "focus": [
    {"id": "something here"},
    {"id": "Another etc"}
    ]
}]



// which template is basically copy and pasted from examples
angular.module('ux').factory('whichTemplate', function () {
     return function (inst) {
        // now we override it with our method so we decide what template gets displayed for each row.
        inst.templateModel.getTemplate = function (item) {
            var name = item.focus ? 'innerFocus' : 'default';
            // now we get the template from the name.
            return inst.templateModel.getTemplateByName(name);
        };
    };
});
```

Trying to iterate a list with the focus array. Any ideas? I think it would make for a great example in the docs. Adding a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/uftsG/88/
Instead of putting all focus array in one li i'm trying to get them spread out while also having the item.obj.name above the list.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with ux-data grid. If you are set on using it, you can ignore this answer, but I did a small search engine (purely for academic reasons) and i ended up using ng-grid to display the data. I followed the github documentation and ended up boot-strapping @scope.myDefs with the data I needed on the backend using a $scope.getMyData function. In the view all you really need to do is add input fields to get the data, and then a div class with your ng-grid. It's super cool because it ensures the code is modular, and there are no funky functions going on in the view with nested ng-repeats so on and so forth. The only part that gave me trouble was the CSS because I'm not bootstrap savvy yet :) Here's some docs if you end up interested in ng-grid at all.

http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/